Using pre-trained models to process MRI images
It is known that MRI images are single-channel, but all pre-trained models accept only three-channel images as input. Therefore, I have a question:

Should I make a three-channel image from a single-channel image or change the pre-trained model so that it can process single-channel images?

For example, in the pre-trained ResNext model, we see that it accepts only three-channel images as input (attached screenshot). Therefore, I cannot use "ResNext" with single-channel MRI images.
It should be noted that a similar situation is observed with the models "ResNet50" and "EfficientNet".
Below is the image for reference:


If you want to use pretrained image modes with single-channel MRI magnitude images, you can just input the same values in all 3 channels:
network_input_batch_rgb_x_y = mri_image_batch_x_y * 1/std * torch.ones(3,1,1, device=mri_image_batch_x_y.device)

where you should choose std as the standard deviation of your dataset
Alternatively, you can add a 1x1 convolution as a first layer, in front of the pretrained network and initialize its weights with 1/std, and the bias with -mean/std.
This way, in fine-tuning the normalization with be changed to match what your pretrained backbone expects.
